# Error when using Yeoman with Angular on Mac OSX

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I'm trying to use Yeoman with my AngularJS app, but I'm getting this error when running 'yo angular'. How do I gain permission to the directory that's throwing up this error?

```
Error: EACCES, permission denied '/Users/mycomputer/.config/configstore/insight-yo.yml'
            You don't have access to this file.

                at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:438:18)
                at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:977:15)
                at Object.create.all.set (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:56:8)
                at Object.Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/configstore.js:19:11)
                at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/node_modules/insight/lib/insight.js:23:34)
                at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/yo/cli.js:27:15)
                at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
                at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
                at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
                at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem:

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```